# Is it safe to use enums across interop boundaries?

Tags: delphi, dll, enums, interop

I'm writing a set of DLLs which allows other developers write their own DLL as an extension. In the Delphi code, I widely use enums, and enum sets. I use enums through DLLs. I know I can safely use an enum through a DLL across different projects compiled with Delphi. However, I'm not sure about how adaptable it is across various languages.

Is it safe to use enums through a DLL while supporting other various languages? Or should I cast it as an integer instead?

Comment: Enums would need to be passed as ordinals, and your Delphi code should use [{$MINENUMSIZE}](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Berlin/en/Minimum_enumeration_size_%28Delphi%29) to ensure that you're using the right size ordinal to be compatible across platforms. Delphi will pack enums into differing byte sized values depending on the number of elements in the enumeration, which can cause some issues passing back and forth with non-Delphi code.

Comment: Use min enum size of 4 for interop because C enums are just int.

Comment: @David: according to C99, they can be smaller than int, if the compiler wants that. But practically, on Windows, they will all be 4 bytes (int) sized.

Comment: This is a Windows question. On Windows C int is 4 bytes.

Comment: On Windows, `int` is 4 bytes indeed, but *an enum* is not necessarily so, as it can be *smaller* than `int`, according to C99. Practically, because Microsoft made it a fait accompli, it is 4 bytes (or 31 bits), though.

Comment: Well, it can't be smaller than `int` because the standard mandates that an `enum` must be able to store every `int` value. But it could be larger than `int`. The reality is that any C compiler that is used for interop has 4 byte enums.

Comment: No, the standard does not. It says "6.7.2.2 Enumeration specifiers ... Each enumerated type shall be compatible with char, ***a*** signed integer type, or ***an*** unsigned integer type. **The choice of type is implementation-defined, but shall be capable of representing the values of all the members of the enumeration.**" (emphasis mine) The integral type must be able to represent all enum values, the enum must not be able to represent all `int` values. And I already said that practically, on Windows, that means it is a 32 bit type.

Comment: @David: Online: http://www.coding-guidelines.com/C99/html/6.7.2.2.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enums need to be passed as integers (Word or DWORD), and you should use the compiler directive [{$MINENUMSIZE}](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Berlin/en/Minimum_enumeration_size_%28Delphi%29) (AKA `{$Z}`) to ensure that they're the proper size. The Delphi compiler will use different sizes based on the number of enum values unless you do so.

If you're planning to interop with C/C++ code on the Windows OS, use `{$MINENUMSIZE 4}`.

The documentation I linked above addresses interop with C/C++ - see the third paragraph:

> The $Z directive controls the minimum storage size of Delphi enumerated types.
>
> An enumerated type is stored as an unsigned byte if the enumeration has no more than 256 values, and if the type was declared in the {$Z1} state (the default). If an enumerated type has more than 256 values, or if the type was declared in the {$Z2} state, it is stored as an unsigned word. Finally, if an enumerated type is declared in the {$Z4} state, it is stored as an unsigned double word.
>
> The {$Z2} and {$Z4} states are useful for interfacing with C and C++ libraries, which usually represent enumerated types as words or double words.